# whats the best way to play a playlist of audio in php on different pages at the same time and at once

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, flash

I am working on a project, in which i need to announce an announcement when a txt file is created on the server and i need to notify all users through an audio announcement,the audio should be played at once on any client browsers that are currently on the pages. the playing of the announcement needs to be synchronized upto maximum accuracy.

the announcement is composed of multiple audio files (playlist).

after the announcement is played on all active clients the txt file will be deleted. and the server will be waiting/looking for another txt file.

for example:
client1 - server time: 19:22:01, Recieved announcement and playing the audio
Client2 - server time: 19:22:01, Recieved announcement and playing the audio

any recommendations? on how to accomplish the announcement at once on all clients, any technique? mysql database or 
Flash, Applets, HTML5 audio, JQuery etc.

Thanks..

Comment: You could use a long poller. It is basically a simple poller that doesn't return until there is data. Let the code in the long poller (usually PHP) poll a database for an event. This case, you could get millisecond accurate polling on your database without creating a lot of data trafic all with off-the-shelve proven technology.

Comment: currently i am using a similar method but there is still a difference of nearly 1.5 seconds. which i want to decrease.

Comment: Find out where that 1.5 seconds come from. We have created long-pollers with 1 minute timeouts and 100ms pollers on the DB which react within that 100ms. (Also: do you really need subsecond precision? Perhaps you are using the wrong tools then.... )

Comment: the tools are html5, php, mysql and polling technique. yes the subsecond precision is important for me.. what tools do you use / recommend.

Comment: In our case, we use PHP/MySQL and basic Ajax. The MySQL poller is using PHP's `usleep` to sleep 100ms between database polls. I put the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a long-poller technique with simple PHP, Ajax en MySQL:

The PHP code is as follows:

```
timeout = 600;
while (timeout > 0) {
    $res = db_query("QUERY");
    $return_value = create_value_from_result($res);

    // see if the result changed
    $db_hash = md5($return_value);

    if ($_SESSION['hash'] == $db_hash) {
        // the result didn't change -- sleep and poll again
        // usleep take microseconds, 100000 is 100 millisecond
        // this is the default database polling interval
        usleep(100000);
        $timeout--;
    } else {
        // the result changed -- reply the result and set the session hash
        $timeout = 0;
        $_SESSION['hash'] = $db_hash;
    }
}
return json_encode($return_value);
```

And the Javascript is simple Ajax (dojo is this case):

```
function longpoll() {
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url: 'longpolling.php',
        load: function (data, ioArgs) {
            data = dojo.fromJson(data);

            do_magic(data);

            // use settimeout to avoid stack overflows
            // we could also use a while(1) loop,
            // but it might give browser errors such as 'script is
            // running too long' (not confirmed)
            setTimeout(longpoll, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

You need the 60 second timeout to make sure the browser doesn't timeout on the Ajax call.

This way, as soon as the result of QUERY changes (a record gets inserted, an update made on a record), the PHP call returns and the Ajax gets its result.

Comment: there is only one problem.. the 60 second timeout can create problem. what if two clients are running? both will show the updated data at how much precision. i want them to show it synchronized.

Comment: If two clients are running, they will each have their own PHP call and their own timeout. The synchronised data will be available to them almost instantaneously. We have used this technique with several clients and numerous data points. The timeout is only there to ensure the browser doesn't give a "server is taking too long to respond" error. Try it out, you'll see it works.